# Halal Restaurants in Seoul South Korea

Tags: food-and-drink, south-korea, dietary-restrictions

I am travelling to Seoul this winter. I want to know about some good restaurants having halal food and also having spicy food as well. If there are some Pakistani restaurants having biryani that will be more good to know.

Comment: Not answering your question, just FYI: I know the ship building town of Geoji in the far south of the country has a large Pakistani community with many restaurants.

Comment: You should enjoy the seafood :)

Answer (score 8):

I hope these links from the official Korea Tourism Organisation website, visitkorea, will help you:

- [Muslim Food Guide](http://www.visitkorea.or.kr/ena/CU/CU_EN_8_1_6.jsp)
- [Religious concerns / Halal Restaurants in Korea](http://english.visitkorea.or.kr/enu/FO/FO_EN_6_6_2.jsp)

Comment: Could you include relevant information in your answer? These links might die.

Answer (score 6):

Usmania International Restaurant

---

> Usmania is a Pakistani restaurant expressing authentic Pakistani taste
>   in both its interior and food. The menu features about a hundred
>   dishes, ranging from whole wheat bread, lamb, beef or chicken, but
>   does not offer any pork dishes or alcoholic beverages, which are
>   prohibited by the Koran. Inside the restaurant, you will find a
>   variety of Pakistani decorations such as traditional shishas (water
>   pipes) and silk carpets. Beef kebabs and tandoori chicken are
>   favorites among Korean diners.
>   Here is the 
>   [Official Website of Usmania Restaurant](http://usmania.com.ne.kr/)

Address: Seoul-si Yongsan-gu Itaewon-dong 119-7
Tel: 02-798-7155
How to get there: Subway Line 6, Itaewon Station Exit 1, 5 minutes’ walk

Comment: As a general guideline, Itaewon is the place to go when looking for halal food. A lots of restaurants owned by people from countries with a mostly muslim population.